# How to create a function that subsets and renames a dataframe column, using output as part of the name, in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, subset, rename

I am trying to select and rename columns from many data frames and would like to make a function. I will eventually merge the subsetted data, so I want to first rename the columns with a prefix that differentiates the data derived from each data frame. How can I make this into a function?

Here is an example, where x is a dataframe.

```
title <- (deparse(substitute(x))) #get the name of the dataframe
myname <- (paste(title, "avg_logFC", sep = "_"))  #make a new variable that pastes the name of the 
dataframe onto the name of the column
test <- x %>%  select(avg_logFC) #How can I rename the new column using the "myname" variable? 
names(test) <- print(myname) #this works, but not within a function.
```

I tried the following function and this did not work:

```
myfunction <- function(x) {  
  x <- as.data.frame(x %>%  select(avg_logFC))
  title <- (deparse(substitute(x))) 
  myname <- (paste(title, "avglogFC", sep = "_"))  
  x <- as.data.frame(x %>% names(x) <- print(myname))
}
```

Comment: Why you are assinging the `print` output to `names`,   You could do this without that.  `x %>% set_names(myname)`

Answer (score 0):

If we are using the pipe, then instead of assingment (`<-`) use the `setNames` (from `base R`) or `set_names` (from `dplyr`) or with `rename`

```
library(dplyr)
myfunction <- function(dat){
    myname <- paste(deparse(substitute(dat)), "avglogFC", sep="_")
    dat %>%
        select(avglogFC) %>%
        rename(!! myname := avglogFC)
  }
```

-testing with a reproducible example

```
data(mtcars)
dat1 <- head(mtcars) %>% 
            mutate(avglogFC =  mean(log(mpg)))  


myfunction(dat1)
#  dat1_avglogFC
#1      3.017272
#2      3.017272
#3      3.017272
#4      3.017272
#5      3.017272
#6      3.017272
```

---

Or another option is `rename_at/rename_all` or `rename_with` from `dplyr 1.0.0`

```
myfunction <- function(dat){
    myname <- paste(deparse(substitute(dat)), "avglogFC", sep="_")
    dat %>%
        select(avglogFC) %>%
        rename_with(~ myname, everything())
  }

myfunction(dat1)
#  dat1_avglogFC
#1      3.017272
#2      3.017272
#3      3.017272
#4      3.017272
#5      3.017272
#6      3.017272
```